# File already opened exclusively by another user

Tags: wine, samba, fstab, file-sharing

I am trying to run a windows application (Enterprise Architect) through Wine. It seems to work perfectly when I work locally. But we have a shared file on a windows share and when running in Windows many users can work in that file at the same time. But when I try to open the file from my ubuntu/samba/wine-setup it claims someone else has locked the file exclusively.

Relevant part of my fstab-file:

```
//host/share /media/ea cifs credentials=/home/xxx/.smbcredentials,users,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0
```

Any ideas for config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another option to your list and see if that fixes things: **nobrl**

```
//host/share /media/ea cifs credentials=/home/xxx/.smbcredentials,users,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,nobrl
```